# Is this proof of Transitivity of the inverse of a transitive relation correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to prove that if $R$ is transitive then its inverse is transitive as well.
$$\begin{align}
  & a{{R}^{-1}}b\,\,,\,\,b{{R}^{-1}}c \\ 
 & \Rightarrow bRa\,\,,\,\,cRb \\ 
 & \Rightarrow cRa \\ 
 & \Rightarrow a{{R}^{-1}}c \\ 
\end{align}$$

is this a correct proof (or am I completely wrong and it's not even true?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A note: What you call "complementary" is conventionally called the inverse relation of $R$. (It's interesting that you got the notation right.) Wikipedia says that alternative terms are converse or transpose relation. I am not sure if "complementary" is used by anyone.

True statement and correct proof.

This statement from wikipedia article on [inverse relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_relation) is relevant:

> If a relation is reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric,
>   asymmetric, transitive, total, trichotomous, a partial order, total
>   order, strict weak order, total preorder (weak order), or an
>   equivalence relation, its inverse is too.

Comment: Great I confused myself and thought I might be wrong :) Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, @Jason. When in doubt, check Wikipedia :)

Comment: The *complement*  of a relation $R$ is defined as the relation $S$ (on the same set) which holds iff $R$ does not hold.  But I have never heard the term in the wild.

Comment: @AndreN Oh yes, thanks for pointing it out. But I sure hope OP did not have this complement in mind.

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: Luckily not, the OP's proof could not be written by someone who was thinking complement.

Comment: @Andre Yes, thank you.

Comment: Hehe, such a discussion about my incorrect translation in a hurry from my language :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that proof looks fine to me.

Comment: And Thanks to you 2 :)